# Does a unique_ptr call the destructor on its own?

Tags: c++

Probably "dumb" question, but I failed to grasp this part of the concept.

Say I have a unique_ptr to a class object and a normal destructor ~Destructor.

my main is just creating the pointer and the object to which it points. If I do nothing else, does it call the destructor? Does it work like a 'new' pointer which doesn't call destructor unless you type delete?

Comment: The core functionality of `unique_ptr` is to make sure the owned object is always automatically destroyed when appropriate. Please share a [MCVE] illustrating your concern rather than try to describe it.

Comment: The whole point of `unique_ptr` - unique but transferrable ownership - is that the object it carries is destroyed when it no longer has an owner. (It is often a mistake to think of the standard "smart pointers" as pointers. Think of them as objects that can be transferred or shared instead.)

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` will automatically call a deleter function when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed.  By default that deleter function applies the C++ `delete` operator to the owned object which runs the destructor and frees the memory.

You can go wrong if you leak the `unique_ptr` instance itself (then it never has a chance to perform its cleanup), if you detach your object from the `unique_ptr` (that tells it not to do cleanup), or if you fail to match the deleter function to the original allocation method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Well the unique ptr has a function object that by default invokes delete on the pointed to object, which calls the destructor.

You can change the type of that default deleter to do almost anything.  The default one has no runtime state (or storage, so zero overhead).

```
std::unique_ptr<int, something_else> ptr=new int(3);
```

that invokes `something_else{}(int *)` when it exits scope.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr=new int(3);
```

that invokes `std::default_delete<int>{}(int *)` when it exits scope, which calls `delete`.

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> ptr(new int(3), [](int* p){ std::cout << "Byeeeee!\n"; delete p; } );
```

that prints then deletes at end of scope.

Comment: Excellent answer with examples! Haha it was just 2 minutes later from another